# Django Comments app: How do I disable the redirection to posted.html?

Tags: django, redirect, comments

I'm using [Django's comments framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/). Whenever someone posts a comment he is redirected to a success page (`posted.html`). I don't want a success page to show up. I just want the current page to be reloaded (with the new comment on it). How do I stop the redirection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding a hidden form field named `next` is the way to go, but you should use `request.get_full_path` because `request.path` doesn't include query strings:

```py
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.get_full_path }}" />
```

Comment: Cool. I didn't know about request.get_full_path. Thanks!

Comment: How does that work if you are overriding the Django comments's `form.html` (ie using `{% render_comment_form %}`)? The template wouldn't know anything about `request`.

Answer (score 1):

From looking through the source in: contrib.comments.views.comments, it looks like you can supply a "next" parameter to override the where the redirect goes.

```
#django.contrib.comments.views.comments

@csrf_protect
@require_POST
def post_comment(request, next=None, using=None):

    #more code here...

    # Check to see if the POST data overrides the view's next argument.
    next = data.get("next", next)

    #more code here...
```

I would try adding a hidden field to the comment form with a name of "next" and a value of the current url you're on. If that doesn't work, you might have to supply your own view and url. Hope that works!

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to hard-code the current url in the html. Is there a way to get the current url? I would like to do something like: `<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ current_url }}" />`. Possible?

Comment: Sure. If you're using: 'django.core.context_processors.request' in your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS, you can do: <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.path }}" />